# Android Unity3d - create a character with movement

Tags: android, animation, unity-game-engine, blender-2.61

I am creating an android application. The objective of my app is to show a character(Men/women) with movement(like walking or something). 
I am new to the unity3d, blender tools.

I put efforts to start my task and I got the following informations,

1) Creating Men / Women character using MakeHuman tool.
2) Import Character to blender tool and armature the character.
3) With the use of this blend file, can create the application in unity3d tool.

Is this correct way to start my app. If yes, can anyone give some samples (or) links that useful for this (or) some guidance. If No, can anyone provide some way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

first of all, you can use whatever modelling tool you want. Mostly used tool is maya(animation). Export your model and animation file to FBX file then you can import it in Unity and can be used to make app. You will find many video tutorials on [3dbuzz](http://www.3dbuzz.com/training/view/unity-fundamentals/basic-terminology) . The document for the exporting and importing object you can find [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectMaya.html). If any doubts, you can join [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37624/unity3d-developers) for unity3d.